# Viewing old version of a file in TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How can I browse through old versions of a file in TortoiseGit? I'm thinking about something like a GUI that you open for a particular file, and it shows you in one pane a list of commits, and in another pane the file contents.

The closest thing I know is the "Show Log" GUI with "View -> View Patch" selected, but I was hoping to be able to see the whole file, not just patch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always do it like this:

1. Show log of 1 file:

[image]

2. select a commit and in the file list below, select "view revision in alternative editor"

[image]

3. Voila

[image]